# What is the difference between monitors and other synchronization primitives

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, mutex, critical-section

What is the actual difference between monitors and other synchronization primitives like mutexes, WinAPI events and critical sections? It looks for me that it's quite the same thing -- one thread at the time can lock the monitor, while other threads should wait for it to become free, much like in the case of events and critical sections.

So, what is the difference? Where am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "monitors"?

Comment: @Jonathan Potter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)

Comment: It is the Swiss army knife of synchronization primitives.  It trivially replaces Mutex but adds elegant solutions for, say, bounded producer/consumer that are hard to implement with mutants or semaphores.  The winapi doesn't provide monitors, you'll have to use a condition variable or the concurrency runtime.

Comment: Read the MSDN documentation: [About Synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681924.aspx). It explains what the various primitives are and how they are used.

Answer (score 0):

All these synchronization primitives under Windows have similar operations(`wait` and `signal`), but slightly different behaviour of these operations. So primitives' usage is usually differs.

1. **Critical section** has *owner* thread, so it can be released(`signal`ed) *only by the owner*.

Also, unlike to other primitives, operations for critical section use *pointer* instead of *HANDLE*, so *critical sections cannot be used by `WaitForMultipleObjects`* and similar functions.

2. **Mutexes** are very similar to critical sections, but they are identified by a *HANDLE*, so they can be waited for together with other objects (using `WaitForMultipleObjects`).

[SignalObjectAndWait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686293(v=vs.85).aspx) function can also be used for mutexes.

3. **Events** support *manually-reset* mode, when successfull *waiting* on event doesn't reset it. So several waiters can bypass *waiting* for single event at the same time.
4. **Semaphores** (WinAPI variant for **monitors**) allows usage limit above 1, that is code section protected by semaphore is no longer exclusive, like with *critical section* and *mutexes*.

Also, semaphores has no *owner* semantic, so they can be signalled by any thread. This feature is critical for some algorithms.